# How to send mail when multiple email ids are store in one excel cell?

Tags: r

I have written loop for 1 email id in 1 excel cell but I am unable to write loop when multiple email ids are store in 1 excel cell

Here's a sample

```
| code   |      email.ids      |        cc            |
|  1     |abc@abc.in;aab@abc.in|as@abc.in;asdb@abc.com|
|  2     |as@abc.in;asdb@abc.in|as@abc.in;asdb@abc.com|

Code Column will the value for forloop
```

Comment: The formatting of your question is messed up, and it’s unclear what you mean. Could you please fix your question’s formatting to make it understandable? (There’s a link with formatting help directly above the text box where you edit the question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A base R option using `ifelse`

```
transform(
  df,
  B = ifelse(A>200,A,NA),
  C = ifelse(A<=200,A,NA)
)
```

gives

```
    A   B   C
1 250 250  NA
2 190  NA 190
3 100  NA 100
4 500 500  NA
5 400 400  NA
```

**Data**

```
df <- data.frame(A = c(250,190,100,500,400))
```

Answer (score 1):

You find the column to put value in based on the value in column A.

```
df <- data.frame(A = c(250, 190, 100, 500, 400))
df$B <- NA
df$C <- NA
df[cbind(1:nrow(df), +(df$A < 200) + 2)] <- df$A
df

#    A   B   C
#1 250 250  NA
#2 190  NA 190
#3 100  NA 100
#4 500 500  NA
#5 400 400  NA
```

where

```
(df$A < 200) + 2 #column number to put A value in
#[1] 2 3 3 2 2
```